# Does one's wife have to observe "early" Shabbat if her husband does?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting

If a man attends an early Shabbat minyan long before the latest candle lighting time (18 mins. before sundown, e.g.) and has started Shabbat before then, must his wife accept Shabbat at the same time that her husband does, or can she wait until she lights candles, later?

Comment: @GershonGold is this not different since here there is a "minyan" the other question was about one person, but it seems when minyan it is different https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.261.4 and  halacha 7 here http://www.chabad.org/3447043/

Answer (score 4):

From [Rabbi Kaganoff's](http://rabbikaganoff.com/starting-shabbos-early/) site:

> **Early hubby**
>
> Rav Moshe Feinstein rules that the fact that a husband was mekabeil
>   Shabbos does not require his wife to do so, just as his making a
>   personal vow or oath is not binding on her (Shu’t Igros Moshe, Orach
>   Chayim [3:38;](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=335) cf. Shu’t Shevet Halevi [7:35](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1417&pgnum=37), who disagrees). He
>   discusses, at length, whether it is permitted for her to do melachah
>   activities for her husband after he was mekabeil Shabbos, and
>   concludes that it is proper that she does not.

Comment: IIRC she can wait until he gets home from shul if she needs to.